# MySQL query statement logic

Tags: mysql

So I am working on a PHP Project where a connection is made to a MySQL database. I get stuck with an SQL statement, because of my (not so well) knowledge of how to create SQL queries.

So here is my situation:

I want to get the latest active auction by the following query

```
SELECT *
FROM `#__wp_auctions`
WHERE `start` <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AND `end` >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + (the max delay of an open auction item)
```

And to get the max delay of a current auction is by the following query

```
SELECT MAX(`delay`)
FROM `#__wp_auction_items`
WHERE `auction` = (over here should be the ID of current auction)
```

Now is there a way to add the two tables together so I can use the result of the first query to enter in the second or the other way around?

For example: get the result of the first query, place the id (of the auction) in second query and afterwards get the max delay and edit the first query with it??

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like that:

```
SELECT *
FROM '#__wp_auctions'
WHERE 'start' <= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
AND 'end' >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + (SELECT MAX('delay')
FROM '#__wp_auction_items' WHERE 'auction' = (over here should be the ID of current auction))
```

Use the second 'Selec' as a statement.

Comment: Current_timestamp is a string of the time right now i'm guessing. Is there a way how I can add minutes to a string in SQL?

Comment: TIMESTAMPADD(MINUTE,30,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);

Comment: But how do i pass the ID from the main query to the subquery(child) ?